# A period of PCM data from ALSA is duplicated

Tags: driver, alsa

Our hardware saves 1024 frames of 16 bit stereo.  I wrote an ALSA driver for it.  PCM data is captured using arecord and saved to a wav file.

`arecord -Dhw:0,0 -t wav -f S16_LE -r 44100 -c 2 -d 2 -v rec.wav`

For debugging, the hardware generates a ramp of 2048 values in bits 11:0 with the ISR counter in bits 15:12.  The wav file is viewed in audacity.

Expected pcm for 8 periods:

```
Ramp start   end
   0h,      7ffh
1800h,     1fffh
2000h,     27ffh
3800h,     3fffh
4000h,     47ffh
5800h,     5fffh
6000h,     67ffh
7800h,     7fffh
```

As seen in audacity

```
   0h,    7ffh
   0h,    7ffh
2000h,   27ffh
2000h,   27ffh
4000h,   47ffh
4000h,   47ffh
6000h,   67ffh
6000h,   67ffh
```

[PCM ramp in audacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdlV6.jpg)

The 1st period of pcm is duplicated twice.  The big jump in the ramp indicates that the 2nd period of pcm is not present.  The 3rd period of pcm is duplicated.  The 4th period of data is is not present.  The 5th period of pcm is duplicated.  The 6th period of data is is not present.

In struct `snd_pcm_hardware`, I have:

```
   .channels_min = 2,
   .channels_max = 2,
   .buffer_bytes_max = (8*4096),
   .period_bytes_min =    4096,
   .period_bytes_max = (2*4096),
   .periods_min = 1,
   .periods_max = 2,
```

Since there's no DMA, I use struct `snd_pcm_ops .copy_user` to copy data to an ALSA buffer passed in `.copy_user`.

I tried the settings below, but arecord had an error.

```
   .periods_min = 1,
   .periods_max = 1,
```

arecord: set_params:1411: Can't use period equal to buffer size 1024 == 1024)

I tried increasing period_max to 4, and it resulted in 4 duplicates

```
   .period_bytes_max = (4*4096),
   .periods_min = 1,
   .periods_max = 4,
```

As seen in audacity

```
   0h,    7ffh
   0h,    7ffh
   0h,    7ffh
   0h,    7ffh
4000h,   47ffh
4000h,   47ffh
4000h,   47ffh
4000h,   47ffh
```

I verified that the ramp values are as expected in the ISR handler.  In .copy_user, I verified that the pos argument isn't the same as the previous copy_user call and that the ramp values are as expected.  Why is it duplicating?  What can I do to fix it?  Thanks in advance.

Added:  Info printed by arecord

```
Recording WAVE 'rec.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
 Bufsz 8192, srate 44100, nch 2
 Opening PCM
 PCM Prepare
 Format 2
 Rate 44100
 Channels 2
 Buffer size 2048
 Period size 1024
  stream       : CAPTURE
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
 PCMptr 0
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 44100
  exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 2048
  period_size  : 1024
  period_time  : 23219
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 1024
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 1
  stop_threshold   : 2048
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 4611686018427387904
  appl_ptr     : 0
  hw_ptr       : 0
```

Comment: This appears to be a bug in your driver. Whose source code you have not shown.

Comment: It might be in snd_pcm_ops .pointer callback.  If the ISR received 1024 frames should the .pointer callback return 1023 (position of last frame received) or 1024 (position of next frame to receive) ?

Comment: The pointer is the boundary between the used and unused parts of the buffer. 1024.

Comment: Update:  There was a pointer error in the driver in which the same data was copied to the ALSA buffer.